# string value is not changing when layout changes

Tags: java, android, variables, android-xml

i have two layout `landscape` and `portrait` in which i set `TextView` value as below:

landscape:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="5" />
```

portrait:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="2" />
```

and i am accessing `TextView` value like this:

**1.**

```
public class GridFragment extends Fragment {
public static TextView tv;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}
}
```

**2.**

```
public class AppConst {    
    public static String str = (String) GridFragment.tv.getText();
    public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

now the problem is it i am receiving `TextView` value only for single time rotation but if i change rotation view the value doesn't change.

what i am trying to say is if i run app in portrait mode i am getting **2 number of columns** but if now change rotation from portrait to landscape the value **should be 5 now**  but the **value is still** 2 when it should change from 2 to 5.

what i mean is it gets value for first time but when screen rotates it doesn't change value.

what i want is: when screen is portrait value should 2 and when screen is landscape value should be 5.

**please note** i am not talking about displaying value on screen instead i am talking about sending / passing value from xml to String.

i am talking about changing / updating value in this method: `public static String str = (String) GridFragment.tv.getText();
    public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = Integer.parseInt(str);`

get current value from specific screen mode.

Comment: You have to re-assign the variable `public static String str = (String) GridFragment.tv.getText();` after your screen rotates.  And then re-parse it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is:

```
public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

`final` really means final once it is set it stays with the value

**To solve this:**
Don't use a constants class... it is the wrong approch, it depends on what you want to do. 
Either save the values in the [Bundle savedInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)  or save the data in the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

And keep in mind that by default **the hole view is recreated** on *orientation change* so the complete creation lifecycle is performed

Comment: THat's half the problem.  The other half is that statics defined and assigned to at class scope would never be re-evaluated, unless the app is terminated.  Rotating the device would cause the activity to be reloaded, but not statics.

Comment: can i use `dimens.xml` to set Number of Column for different size and rotation, like `values-land/dimens.xml, values-larg-land/dimens.xml` and send valuu to `String str;`

Comment: Setting it through dimens.xml should be possible, but you should avoid using your constant class